# Calculate the area of a closed curve after mapping on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I want to calculate the area of a closed curve $\gamma_r$ which is the image of $C_r:|z|=r(r>2)$ with the map $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{z-1}$. I know that the area of $S$ can be written as $\frac{1}{2i}\int_{\partial S}\bar{z}dz$ in complex analysis, so I am thinking about calculating $\frac{1}{2i}\int_{\gamma_r}\bar{\omega}d\omega$ with the transform $\omega=\frac{z^2}{z-1}$. But it is still difficult for me to compute the final result. I have no idea about how to handle with conjugation terms. Am I on the right track?

Comment: the circle of radius $r$ has the equation $z \bar z = r^2$, which gives you a way to express $\bar z$ in terms of $z$ inside the integral

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thank you :)